# When, where, and why should a comments conversation be moved?

Tags: discussion, support, comments

I've seen comments threads on many posts grow out of control.

I've seen two ways to handle this so far - one is the automatic "move to chat" feature and the other seems more user suggested - "let's talk about this in meta".

Under what reasons should a comment thread be moved, where is the appropriate place, and when should that occur?

Comment: It all depends on what's being discussed, doesn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moving to a chat only makes sense if both parties are actually interested in a realtime chat. Normally, this means that the community member who's responding has to be interested to discuss something which apparently has already proven difficult to communicate convincingly to the asker.

So as far as I can see, the *suggestion* of moving to a chat is nice, but it can never be more than a suggestion. If a point proves difficult to make, for whatever reason, one of the parties may simply wish to let it be and move on. Automatically moving anything won't change that. If the comments are really *getting in the way* of the question receiving attention that it should rightfully be getting (e.g. if the out-of-control conversation was getting off-topic and scaring other visitors away), then you should flag the question and have a moderator *remove* the comments.

Comment: +1 for "getting in the way of the question".  I have seen people sabotage answers with pointless red herrings and quibbles for what seem to be nothing more than a love of trolling.

Comment: @MikePennington: Yeah, it's definitely a realistic scenario that some third parties take over a comment section for some seemingly unconnected or unmotivated reason. If it's on an answer, I normally don't mind, but on a question it may seriously keep people away who would otherwise have engaged...

Comment: Kerrick the answer scenario is troubling as well if you can introduce FUD about the quality of someone's answer / credibility.  If the comments are meaningful and both parties work towards agreement that's great.  If one party just wants to get attention and create FUD, it's still a problem on an answer

Comment: @MikePennington: that maybe so, but I've since taken a rather distanced stance towards discussions on my own answers. I can't defend my answers against every possible accusation (time-wise, I mean), so if I see a comment that I can't get any improvement of my answer out of, I sometimes just leave it alone. Sometimes someone else will step in and keep the back-and-forth alive, but I don't always feel the need to babysit that. Rather, I hope that the general community's feedback (= votes) will provide sufficient feedback on the quality and utility of my answer, and that normally works just fine.

Comment: True, and that approach works *if the community understands the details of the argument*.  Some beta sites don't have a strong community around them, so there is a different dynamic at play.  Also, if the troll says something like: "I emailed so and so at the standards body and he agrees with me", those kind of comments are difficult, as it relies on self-reinforcing hearsay but it looks credible enough to scare upvoters.

Comment: @MikePennington: I can't really speak for non-SO sites. I appreciate that they dynamics there may be entirely different...

Answer (score 7):

When the discussion is about the site and its policies:

- Why a question is closed
- Why a question should be reopened
- All the mods are evil
- [The mods hates me, the community hates me, might as well go write worms](http://kids.niehs.nih.gov/games/songs/childrens/worms.htm)
- etc..

These are questions for meta, where one can discuss the, well, meta aspects of the question and how it fits into the site as a whole.

---

When the discussion is about the content of a question or an answer:

- A disagreement on how Java's garbage collection differ's from C#'s.
- A series of back and forth tying to get at the core of the XY problem that a question is asking
- People making silly, back and forth about if someone is a unicorn or a lizard

These are things that aren't appropriate for discussion on meta as such and can be more easily handled in chat (note that these are things that often require a dense back and forth between the person posting the question or answer and another person - meta is no better than the main site for hosting such discussions).

Comment: **+1** for musical reference